# Add MapRoute for a static resource ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, url-routing

I have a pdf file which I would like to a create a route map for it. Is there a way to make object default take a url in stead of action controller combination?

Instead of

```
 routes.MapRoute("MyRouteName", "MyNiceUrl", new { controller = "ControllerName", action = "ActionName" });
```

Have something like

```
 routes.MapRoute("MyRouteName", "MyNiceUrl", new { relativeUrl="MyrelativeUrl" });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need routes for static resources. You need url helpers to reference them:

```
<a href="<%= Url.Content("~/Content/test.pdf") %>">Download pdf</a>
```

And if you wanted to have an url like `/SomeController/MyNiceUrl` to serve your pdf file you could simply write a controller action:

```
public ActionResult MyNiceUrl()
{
    var pdf = Server.MapPath("~/Content/test.pdf");
    return File(pdf, "application/pdf");
}
```

and then:

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("Download pdf", "MyNiceUrl", "SomeController") %>
```

Answer (score 0):

As in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1363415/174971):

Use your controller, or create a mini-controller, and then use the Redirect ActionResult:

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Pdf()
    {
        return Redirect( Url.Content( "mydoc.pdf" ) );
    }

}
```