# Rewriting url in asp.net-mvc4 (razor) with extention

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, routes

Default of asp.net-mvc4 is `http://domainname.com/products/1` with routes

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Products",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Products", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

and I want to rewrite to `http://domainname.com/products/1.html` that has .html extention .
Any ideas for this?

Comment: Why would you want to do this?  You're not working with files here.

Comment: I don't want to do it but this is the ideas of customer

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Products",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}.html",
    defaults: new { controller = "Products", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Comment: I don't know, may be. But if ID parameter is null, the url will `code:http://domainname.com/product/.html', not right

Comment: True, I think you should make a separate route to handle that situation.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to put .html extension to a query string or route parameter?

if you take a website with html files, the extension is with the page not with the parameters. Don't know if you have any specific requirement to put it always at the end of the url. but it doesn't make any sense.

```
routes.MapRoute(
name: "Products",
url: "{controller}/{action}.html/{id}",
defaults: new { controller = "Products", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

you might have problems with iis after doing the above, please take a look at this discussion as well.
[ASP.NET MVC Routing - add .html extension to routes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9331516/asp-net-mvc-routing-add-html-extension-to-routes)