# Asp.net mvc routing - how to allow .html extension in mvc routing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

Controller Name is : TestController

Action Name is :HtmlContent

and Url : localhost:53907/en_US/Index.html

***I would like to call HtmlContent action from TestController if url which contains .html extension.***

I have placed breakpoint in HtmlContent but its not hitting if i enter url like mentioned above,

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "MyCustomRoute",
    url: "en_US/{pagename}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Test", action = "HtmlContent" },
    constraints: new {pagename = @".*?$(?<=\.html)" }
);
```

How to write routing for this requirement?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9331516/asp-net-mvc-routing-add-html-extension-to-routes

Comment: Thanks its resolved my problem. Please explian code <add path="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" />
      </httpHandlers>

Answer (score 1):

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "MyCustomRoute",
    url: "en_US/{pagename}.html",
    defaults: new { controller = "Test", action = "HtmlContent" },
    constraints: new {pagename = @".*?$(?<=\.html)" }
);
```

and add code on web.config

```
<add name="HtmlFileHandler" path="*.html" verb="GET" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
```

its work for me if any query .please comment