# How to redirect all requests to html files

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, redirect

I rewrote my website from pure html file paths to MVC 4 extensionless urls.

Now I want to implement rule to redirect all requests to the old `.html` files to my home page.

In `routeConfig.cs` I tried this:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Redirects",
            url: "posts/{page}.html",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
        );
```

But, no matter what I try, I get a 404. I looks like MVC is processing .html files and ignoring my `Route` entry.

I also tried:

routes.IgnoreRoute("posts/{file}.html");

to tell MVC to not process .html files but still no luck.

Any ideas what I"m doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC Routing - add .html extension to routes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9331516/asp-net-mvc-routing-add-html-extension-to-routes)

Comment: MVC uses only .cshtml and .aspx  pages. Why dont you try putting all your HTML content into a cshtml file

Comment: I have done that. The problem is that old links that exist in google are getting 404's, so I need to redirect them to my home page.

Answer (score 2):

Please make routes.RouteExistingFiles to true as per below code snippet.

```
routes.RouteExistingFiles = true;

        routes.MapRoute(name: "Redirects",
            url: "HtmlPage.html",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Html", page = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Also edit your web.config and add PageHandlerFactory-Integrated-HTML handlers to the list of handlers as per below code snippet.

```
<system.webServer>
<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
<handlers>
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
  <add name="PageHandlerFactory-Integrated-HTML" path="*.html"
           verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG" type="System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory"
           resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="integratedMode" />
</handlers>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're migrating from HTML to MVC, I think you shouldn't make the migration part of your application.
Rather, use URL Rewrite module ([URL Rewrite](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite)) to redirect requests.

You can use the IIS Management Console to configure the redirection rules, or edit web.config directly.

Here's a sample of a rule in web.config that can be relevant to your case:

```
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="Html to MVC" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url=".*/(.*).html" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="/Index/{R:1}" redirectType="Found" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

It might not be the perfect rule for what you need (do some testing and tweaking), but I believe it is the way to do what you need. This way you'll be able to eventually get rid of the HTML redirection at some point and it won't be a part of your application; which also means that you don't need to recompile your application to make changes.