# restrict access to the users

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I nave to allow users of my intranet to load any HTML pages.
Users can load only the html pages that start with their username, for example:

```
User: 972547J 
Pages: 972537J*****.HTML
```

I used asp.NET and VB.net, i created a gridview only with the linkbutton of the pages with `972537J****.HTML` (for this user)

That pages are confidentially, then i don't want that users change manually the link and show the HTML pages of other users.

Can i deny users not open html pages of others? With web config setting or iis7 config?
The HTML pages are not editable

Comment: you only show the link for the user that can have access instead of showing other's link,  can you show your code behind `linkbutton` and `gridview` , how you fill `gridview` and how you manage to show `linkbutton`??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first step is to setup [IIS to handle](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770990(v=ws.10).aspx) `.html` files using the `asp.net`

And the second step is to use the `global.asax` to check the file names with the user login if they allowed to view them.

Here is a simple code to start, belong to `global.asax`:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    // you may need this
    HttpApplication app = (HttpApplication)sender;

    // start by check if is html file
    string cTheFile = HttpContext.Current.Request.Path;
    string sExtentionOfThisFile = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(cTheFile);

    if (sExtentionOfThisFile.Equals(".html", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
    {
        // check if the user is logged in
        if(  HttpContext.Current.User == null || 
             HttpContext.Current.User.Identity == null || 
            !HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
          )
        {
            // redirect him where you like
        }
        else
        {
            // make the rest test here
            // HttpContext.Current.User.Identity
        }
    }
}
```

reference for the handler:
[Using ASP.NET routing to serve static files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1149750/using-asp-net-routing-to-serve-static-files)
[ASP.NET MVC Routing - add .html extension to routes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9331516/asp-net-mvc-routing-add-html-extension-to-routes)
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770990(v=ws.10).aspx