# ASP.net MVC 5 Route with two parameter

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want create web application with 2 parameter. Add this Code to **RegisterRoutes** function:

```
routes.MapRoute(
               "pageroute",                                              
               "page/{pageid}/{pagename}",                          
               new { controller = "page", action = "Index", pageid = "", pagename = "" } 
           );
```

and add this method in **pageController**:

```
  public ActionResult Index(int pageid,string pagename)
        {
            return View();
        }
```

Now when i running application with this parameter

```
http://localhost:1196/page/4/Pagename
```

Application run successfully but when running with this parameter

```
http://localhost:1196/page/4/Pagename.html
```

Application return 404 error

```
HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.
```

while add .html in parameter return 404 error. **why?**

Comment: when ulr contains the ".html"  then request goes to html pipeline for handling request at iis . You have to force all request through the ASP.NET pipeline.

Comment: agreed with Sain Pradeep

Comment: @SainPradeep How to force to process request with ASP.net?

Comment: @dinav Ahrie I use MVC not have .aspx file and page1.html is name of page saved in my database when user call this URL application load page1.html from database and create page and returned to user

Comment: pagename is parameter sending to index method of Page controller

Comment: Please refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9331516/asp-net-mvc-routing-add-html-extension-to-routes

Comment: @SainPradeep Thank you i check this link but my problem not resolve

Comment: why not just send the name of the page without the extension ? if the extension can be different than '.html' add string extension to the method signature and inside the method, construct your full page name

Answer (score 1):

Because by default HTML files are not being served through MVC/IIS.

Your application looks for a **physical** file named *Pagename.html* and cannot find it there. Hence - 404.

To make it work, you need to setup your IIS to catch requests for files with HTML extension and pass this request to MVC.

EDIT: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9331516/asp-net-mvc-routing-add-html-extension-to-routes) is a similar question where OP found a solution by switching "Managed Pipeline Mode" to "Classic".

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the Route to:

```
routes.MapRoute(
           "pageroute",                                              
           "page/{pageid}/{*pagename}",                          
           new { controller = "page", action = "Index", pageid = "", pagename = "" } 
       );
```

This will then match everything as in `page/1/*` so the `.html` should go via this route.

I was unable to reproduce an issue where a .html file gave a 404 using a scenario similar to the question, so there may be some other routing issue or IIS configuration causing this.