# URL Routing - HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found, 0x80070002 in IIS 8.0

Tags: asp.net, iis, url-routing

I have created Routing Rules in my `ASP.NET` application. It is working fine on my Laptop `IIS 7.0` server. But when It is on server, it is showing HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found. Server have `IIS 8.0` only.

My Routing rule is as below :
**Global.asax :**

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        RegisterRoutes();
}

private static void RegisterRoutes()
{
        System.Web.Routing.RouteTable.Routes.Add(
                "Login", new System.Web.Routing.Route("Login.html",
                                    new DisplayRouteHandler("~/Login.aspx")));
}
```

If I don't use .html in routing rule then it is working fine on server but with .html, it is not working.
**Detailed Error Information :**

```
Module     IIS Web Core
Notification       MapRequestHandler
Handler    StaticFile
Error Code     0x80070002
Requested URL      http://www.theprojectjugaad.com:80/Login.html
Physical Path      D:\Inetpub\vhosts\jeetenparmar.com\theprojectjugaad.com\Login.html
Logon Method       Anonymous
Logon User     Anonymous
```

Please help me to solve this.

Comment: This answer mentions that [IIS sees the .html and handles the request before ASP.net has a chance](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9331587/3585500).

Comment: @ourmandave, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the Application Pool from Classic to Integrated fixed the issue.