# Which versions of IE support PNG favicons?

Tags: html, image, internet-explorer, cross-browser, favicon

[**In this old StackOverflow post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1344122/favicon-png-vs-favicon-ico-why-should-i-use-pngs-instead-of-icos), it was said that only IE6 had issues with PNG favicons, [**but on channel9**](http://channel9.msdn.com/Forums/TechOff/246218-PNG-Favicons-in-IE7-with-fallback-to-ICO-Favicon-in-pre-IE7), it said that IE7 also does not support PNG favicons either.

But, unfortunately, the channel9 link has been deleted - so does anyone know the official/tested information that states which version of IE started to support PNG favicons?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

### The short answer:

IE11 is the first version of Internet Explorer to support the direct usage of `.png` and `.gif` file format favicons.

### Why the confusion?

As you mentioned, [**some seem to have implied that .png favicons are supported in IE7+**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1344122/favicon-png-vs-favicon-ico-why-should-i-use-pngs-instead-of-icos), while others have stated the opposite.

I believe the confusion is caused by the fact that `.png` images can be used **inside** `.ico` files (`.ico` files are just image container files after all) as of IE7, which is true .

However, previously, direct `.png` favicons were only ever compatible with the other major browsers (Chrome, Firefox etc).

### Proof of direct `.png` Favicon compatibility in IE11 and beyond:

The [**File Format support**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon#File_format_support) section on the [**Favicon wikipedia page**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon) resembles the following:

[image]

**[[20]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon#cite_note-ericlaw-1-20)** points to an article called [**Fun with Favicons**](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2013/09/08/internet-explorer-favicons-png-link-rel-icon-caching.aspx) written by Eric Law, an ex-Microsoft employee and 2013 Microsoft MVP.

The article includes the following:

> IE11 shows some significant improvements in Favicon support:
>
> - Favicons may be changed dynamically using script.
> - The Favicon URL may point directly at a GIF file.
> - The Favicon URL may point directly at a PNG file.

Note though, that it may not be the best idea to use direct `.png` favicons due to compatibility issues with older versions of IE, as mentioned by Eric in the same blog post:

> "Of course, just because you can point at a `.png` or `.gif` doesn't mean
>   you should-- for both compatibility and experience reasons (remember
>   `.ico` can hold multiple image sizes to best suit the display context)
>   you should continue to use a `.ico` as your favicon."

Another article written by Mr.Law, called [**IE11 Changes**](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2013/09/24/10451776.aspx), also briefly mentions IE11's support for direct `.png` and `.gif` file format favicons.

### Proof of `.png` Favicon incompatibility in IE10 and before:

There are many official and non official sources proving that IE10 and before only support `.ico` Favicons.

As of 13/10/2013, the 'file format support' section of the Favicon Wikipedia page resembles the following:

[image]

A 2012 article on MSDN called  [**How to Add a Shortcut Icon to a Web Page**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537656%28VS.85%29.aspx) contains the following snippet:

> "Note that shortcut icons in image formats other than `.ico` — for
>   instance, `.bmp`, `.gif`, or `.png` — **cannot be displayed in Internet
>   Explorer**."

A few quotes from non-official sources:

> "First, IE requires an actual icon file. Not just a `jpg` or `png` renamed
>   with an `ico` extension." - [**Greg Hostetler, Setting up Favicons in IE7.**](http://greghostetler.com/2009/02/setting-up-favicons/).
>
> "It must be windows icon format instead of PNG or GiF, IE8 just
>   supports ICO." - [**xyberbit, MSDN.**](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/iewebdevelopment/thread/a6fb09ef-aa3e-4e9e-be44-edbfad322657).
>
> "On the other hand, Internet Explorer does not support PNG favicons,
>   but it will ignore the PNG favicon and use the ICO favicon, regardless
>   of the order in which they are declared." - [**Jonathon T.Neal**](http://www.jonathantneal.com/blog/understand-the-favicon/).
>
> "One. Big. Problem. IE10 does not support conditional comments, and it
>   does not support PNG favicons." -  [**Jonathon T.Neal**](http://www.jonathantneal.com/blog/understand-the-favicon/)

### Other queries answered:

> Can I just re-name the filetype from `.png` to `.ico` and vice-versa to
>   get around this incompatibility issue?

Sadly not (tested by @[**Truerror**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2308365/truerror) on the 17/06/2013 in IE10). IE10 and before requires an actual icon (`.ico`) file.

> Should it be an 16x16 `.ico`?

Here's what [**Microsoft**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537656%28VS.85%29.aspx) have to say about that:

> "Consider creating both a 16x16-pixel icon as well as a 32x32-pixel
>   icon (and larger, bandwidth permitting), since on high-DPI displays,
>   Internet Explorer may stretch the icon to fit the available space."

Comment: Would an .ico file renamed to .png still be considered ico file? For example, I renamed favico.ico to favico.png. It was originally ico, but is it now still ico, or is it considered a legit png?

Comment: @Truerror I don't think so, I think they need to be converted properly (you could use websites such as http://icotopng.com/ or http://convertico.com/)

Comment: Confirmed. Made a barebone blog with appengine, and used favicon.png instead of the usual ico. IE10 couldn't recognize it.

Comment: Go ahead. And I must say, I'm a bit disappointed with IE. Why MS decided to not support non-ico favicons are beyond me. :P

Comment: Any more info for the size? Should be 16x16 ico?

Comment: @Howard According to Microsoft (msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537656%28VS.85%29.aspx), "Consider creating both a 16 x 16-pixel icon as well as a 32 x 32-pixel icon (and larger, bandwidth permitting), since on high-DPI displays, Internet Explorer may stretch the icon to fit the available space."

Comment: @Truerror, you can include a PNG encoded page *inside* the ico on any IE version since Windows Vista

Answer (score 2):

There is not any version of Internet Explorer which can support PNG favicon.

This is very good article on Favicon http://www.jonathantneal.com/blog/understand-the-favicon/

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon

Comment: With that double negative, do you mean they do or do not support it?

Comment: IE does not support PNG favicons

Comment: Then you might want to consider updating your answer, because it currently states that 'Not any version doesn't support it', which when crossing out the negatives says that 'All versions support it'.

Answer (score 1):

IE8+ Supports .png's  this might be usefull to : http://www.w3.org/2005/10/howto-favicon

Answer (score 0):

No .png favicons are fully supported in any version of IE. However, they may be partially supported in IE 8 and above.