# Favicon not working on webpage in IE10 and below

Tags: html, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9, internet-explorer-10, favicon

Why is the favicon on this webpage not working in IE10 and lower? The webpage is [here](https://www.riteaid.com). It works in IE11 as well as other major browsers.

Here is the code on the top of the page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html dir="ltr" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en"> 
    <head>
        <title>...</title>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8,IE=9" >
        <!-- (various stylesheet, script, and meta declarations) -->
        <link rel="Shortcut Icon" href="/riteAid-theme/images/custom/riteaid.ico" />
        <!-- (more stylesheets and scripts) -->
        <link rel="canonical" href="..." />
    </head>
```

Things I have tried (to no avail):

- Setting `type="image/x-icon"` in the link declaration.
- Setting `rel="icon"` in the link declaration.
- Setting the declaration higher up in the head.
- Changing the name of the icon to `favicon.ico`

I am using a new virtual machine instance between attempts, so caching is not the issue.

Comment: Have you tried lowercasing the rel (don't know if that would actually make a difference)? This is the declaration I usually use and it works in all browsers: `<link rel="shortcut icon" href=".../favicon.ico">`. It may also be a badly encoded .ico file. You can always use a .png for the image as well

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the .ico file is in the wrong format (PNG or GIF). See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16943609).