# Tab Image not working in IE

Tags: html, favicon

I am trying to create an image to appear in the tab that comes up for my website.  The image appears in Firefox, but not in Internet Explorer (I have version 8).  Does anyone know why?

```
<html dir="%Direction" lang="%LanguageISO">
<head>
<title></title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="https://test-t2.int.ps.test.com/cs/ps/cache/Z_PNC_FAVICON_PNG_553.png"/>
```

Comment: Well, this is just a guess, but I'm wondering if HTTPS has anything to do with it. Is your website on the same exact domain, including HTTPS? (Some browsers handle cross-domain rules slightly differently)

Comment: the url starts with https:// yes...

Comment: The URL in the code refers to a page with invalid certificate, and a retrieve operation causes a redirection loop. So it appearently is not the *real* URL.

Answer (score 3):

As per mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16943609/which-versions-of-ie-support-png-favicons), the first version of `IE` which supports `png favicon` is v 11.

Comment: so what can I do so that this one supports it?

Comment: I recommend you to take a look over the .ico file format, and online ico converters

Comment: <html dir="%Direction" lang="%LanguageISO">
<head>
<title></title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="https://test-t2.int.ps.test.com/cs/ps/cache/Z_PNC_FAVICON_ICO_556.ico"/>

Comment: Are you sure your link works properly ? I'm not able to see your icon from my computer when pasting your link in my address bar.