# ASP.NET 4 routing question

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-routing

I am trying to do the following in my Global.asax file:

At the moment i have to define my route like this:

```
routes.MapPageRoute(
    "ViewPage", 
    "pages/{slug}",
    "~/viewpage.aspx",
    false
);
```

Notice the word pages before the `{slug}`

Now if i define it like this:

```
routes.MapPageRoute (
    "ViewPage", 
    "{slug}",
    "~/viewpage.aspx",
    false
);
```

It does not work.

My CSS and JS files wont load, i get a 404.

But, if i do this:

```
routes.MapPageRoute (
    "ContactPage", 
    "contact",
    "~/contact.aspx",
    false
);
```

It works fine??

Basically i want my urls to look like this:

`example.com/contact` or `example.com/about-us` and it is all served dynamically from the database based on the {slug}.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using:

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("slug", 
                "{slug}",
                "~/page.aspx", false);
```

Works fine for me. What you need to make sure is that your routes are in the right order; specific to general but also have an ignore one for resources etc. otherwise they'll be routed there too.

Hope that helps

**Edit**

Ignore routes like:

```
RouteTable.Routes.Ignore("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
```

Comment: +1 - Solution is similar to http://www.stevefenton.co.uk/Content/Blog/Date/201101/Blog/The-Nicest-URLs-In-ASP-NET-MVC/

Answer (score 1):

[How to ignore route in asp.net forms url routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273447/how-to-ignore-route-in-asp-net-forms-url-routing)

Maybe something like this, although I cannot test it at the moment. From what I understand it should tell the routing handler to ignore anything in those directories.

```
routes.Add(new Route("images/", new StopRoutingHandler()));
routes.Add(new Route("js/", new StopRoutingHandler()));
routes.Add(new Route("css/", new StopRoutingHandler()));
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks guys!!

I had to re-order my routes.

I use a HttpHandler to combine and gzip my js and css files.  This was being added last like so:

```
const string combine = "~/code/httphandlers/httpcombiner.ashx";
RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
RouteTable.Routes.Add(new Route("combine", new HttpHandlerRoute(combine)));
```

I switched these around to:

```
const string combine = "~/code/httphandlers/httpcombiner.ashx";
RouteTable.Routes.Add(new Route("combine", new HttpHandlerRoute(combine)));
RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
```

I added the StopRoutingHandler for the webresource.axd and now it all works beautiful!