# ASP.NET 4 URL Routing Web Forms breaks my relative paths to Styles, Scripts, Images, etc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, url-routing, asp.net-mvc-routing, webforms

I have an app with links like so in default.aspx...

```
<link href="Styles/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.8.14.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="Scripts/json2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.6.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.14.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery.tmpl.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Once I added URL Routing it broke my relative paths.  So if I get deep into a route then the page can't find images, scripts, etc.  I would imagine that my jQuery service calls are probably broken as well.  Is there a way other than adding "/" to the beginning of every relative reference to fix this.  In my global.asax I currently have...

```
void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{

    routes.MapPageRoute(
        "EntityRoute", 
        "{entityID}", 
        "~/Default.aspx");        

    routes.MapPageRoute(
        "GlobalSearchRoute",
        "{entityID}/{guarantorID}/{guarDOB}",
        "~/Default.aspx");
}
```

Can I add something here that would allow my relative paths to function without changing all of those paths in the site?

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Routes.IgnoreRoute** in global.asax to exclude those routes that reference your static content:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("Styles/{*pathInfo}");
routes.IgnoreRoute("Scripts/{*pathInfo}");
routes.IgnoreRoute("Images/{*pathInfo}");
```

etc.

Comment: Yes, apparently, but the notation is slightly different:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/273447/how-to-ignore-route-in-asp-net-forms-url-routing

Comment: It occurred to me that this is a client side problem by the time this happens so the only way to fix this would be in the code itself.  I would either have to move away from the relative reference of "Images/" to "/Images/" or I would have to wrap serverside code around those links and preprocess them before they exploded in the browser - like with <%= Url.Content( or something like that.  I ended up just fixing the problem by using the absolute reference "/".  Thanks for trying to help me though.

Comment: routes.IgnoreRoute is a method of Class RouteCollectionExtensions inside System.Web.Mvc Namespace

use routes.Ignore for WebForms

Comment: I wish we could find a proper solutoin to this. My issue is that my websites are setup in to virtual directories. So I'll have to add "/vir-dir-name", and I really don't want to do that.. :-/

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the html base tag.

In the aspx:

```
<base id="baseControl" runat="server" />
```

In the code behind:

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    baseControl.Attributes.Add("href", Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) + VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/"));
}
```

Hope this helps.